# Perform command every X seconds

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, sleep, watch

I wish to perform a command ever 10 seconds, and have it executed in the background (thereby eliminating `watch`?).  All the answers show something like the following, but this will execute ever 11 to 14 seconds.  How can this be accomplished?

```
while true; do
    # perform command that takes between 1 and 4 seconds
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: maybe with real-time signals. and proper handling of leap seconds. good luck.

Comment: @mikeserv  So, don't bother trying?  I don't care about milli-second accuracy, just say half a second.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I find that a task that has to run with that sort of frequency is usually a workaround for another problem.

Comment: @Sobrique  Exactly.  I am doing a proof of concept of a polling data logger.  In reality, it will be programmed in some other language, but this works for now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about:

```
( # In a subshell, for isolation, protecting $!
  while true; do
    perform-command & # in the background
    sleep 10 ;
    ### If you want to wait for a perform-command
    ### that happens to run for more than ten seconds,
    ### uncomment the following line:
    # wait $! ;
    ### If you prefer to kill a perform-command
    ### that happens to run for more than ten seconds,
    ### uncomment the following line instead:
    # kill $! ;
    ### (If you prefer to ignore it, uncomment neither.)
  done
)
```

ETA: With all those comments, alternatives, and the subshell for extra protection, that looks a whole lot more complicated than it started.  So, for comparison, here's what it looked like before I started worrying about `wait` or `kill`, with their `$!` and need for isolation:

```
while true; do perform-command & sleep 10 ; done
```

The rest is really just for when you need it.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind your code dump?

Comment: Also, to cite which shell your code works for (like mikeserv's answer) so people don't get confused when a different shell behaves differently :)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I figured the comments would explain the reasoning.  I'm not sure what's unclear.

Comment: For example: Why the first line, after the `while` doesn't end with `;`? Why the `wait`? Why you don't store the value of `$!` inside a variable, after you call the command?

Comment: @Ash The question was tagged `bash`, so that's where I tested it, but it's pretty basic Bourne shell, isn't it?  I haven't tested it all over, but it should also work in sh, dash, ksh, zsh, etc … the only shells I'm familiar with that won't handle it, are the C shells (csh, tcsh). :)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You mean a semicolon after the `do`? That would be a syntax error; I didn't figure I'd need to explain shell basics.  The wait (or not) is if you want to wait (or not) for a perform-command that happens to run for more than the ten allotted seconds.  (Now that you mention it, an alternative would be `kill $!`, when you don't want to wait, but don't want to let it continue either.)  Why not storing $! in another variable?  I didn't think of it. :)  And now I'm thinking of it, I think I'd prefer running this in a subshell. Hmm …

Comment: The semicolon I was refering to was after `perform-command &`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel  Ah.  I never use semicolons after `&`.  In fact, I that would also be a syntax error, at least in bash.

Comment: I guess that clears all the empty holes.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I've updated the code with rephrasing of the `wait` explanation, adding the `kill` alternative you made me think of (funny how that's a good thing, eh?), and a subshell for protecting $!, as you point out it might need.  I think that's better; thanks. :)

Comment: You're welcome. But won't the `sleep` change the value of `$!`?

Comment: The bash manual says of `$!`: "Expands to the process ID of the job most recently placed into the background," and the `sleep` is not placed into the background, so no, it won't. :)

Comment: Nice one. Thank you. That should be rock-solid now.

Comment: @TheSidhekin you pose a fair point :P My bad.

Comment: @Sidhekin - no, it isn't basic Bourne shell. `wait` is `bash`.

Comment: @mikeserv Really? Got a reference for that?  I'm pretty sure it's been part of Bourne shell since 1979 at least: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/bourne/v7/ – although I could be wrong (I was not doing Unix at the time), I'd appreciate a reference. :)

Comment: no. there's no reference for a command that doesn't exist. `wait` is not Bourne. try it yourself.

Comment: @mikeserv Not only have I tried it, and found it working in every Bourne shell implementation I have at hand, I've found it in several manual pages, including the linked one from 1979. Have you tried it?  If so, in which version of the Bourne shell?

Comment: ok. `wait` *is* bourne. my apologies. it is definitely not POSIX, though.

Comment: @mikeserv … http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wait.html …

Comment: wow. wrong on both counts. when did that happen?

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like the following in `bash`, `zsh`, or `ksh`:

```
SECONDS=0
while   command
do      sleep "$((10-(SECONDS%10)))"
done
```

Here's what the `bash` manual says about `$SECONDS`:

> `$SECONDS`
>
> - Each time this parameter is referenced, the number of seconds since shell invocation is returned. If a value is assigned to `$SECONDS`, the value returned upon subsequent references is the number of seconds since the assignment plus the value assigned. If `$SECONDS` is `unset`, it loses its special properties, even if it is subsequently reset.

Here's a working example:

```sh
(   SECONDS=0
    while   sleep   "$((RANDOM%10))"
    do      sleep   "$((10-(SECONDS%10)))"
            echo    "$SECONDS"
    done
)
```

---

```
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
```

Comment: To avoid resetting `SECONDS` do `sleep "$((10-(($SECONDS-$start_time)%10)))"`. You will have to do `start_time=$SECONDS` before loop.

Comment: @richard - why avoid it?

Comment: because one day you will have it in a script that you call from with-in such a loop. And you will spend all day wondering why it is not working properly. In short, it does not nest, if you reset `SECONDS`. Spawning a sub-shell as in your latest edit, should also avoid this problem.

Comment: @richard - since the question was regarding a `while true` loop I didn't figure any shell state was expected to survive it. Wrapping a loop like that in its own context is usually best practice, anyway. In a situation like that I would be more concerned about doing so for `trap`'s sake than for `$SECONDS`' sake, though.

Comment: Thanks Mike,  I was thinking to do something similar (but didn't yet know the specifics how).  But Sidhekin's solution seems to do the same thing, no?  I am not qualified to make judgement on the better answer, but felt obligated to pick something.

Comment: +1 for referencing the manual, not enough answers on this site cites their answers with actual documentation.

Comment: A note of caution.  An edge condition could result in 20 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

BASH only - You could also compute time spent by your command and subtract from 10:

```
TIMEFORMAT=$'%0R'
while true; do
    T=$({ time command; } 2>&1)
    sleep $(( 10-T ))
```

From BASH man:

> TIMEFORMAT The value of this parameter is used as a format string
>   specifying how the timing information for pipelines prefixed  with 
>   the time  reserved  word  should  be displayed.  The % character
>   introduces an escape sequence that is expanded to a time value or
>   other information.  The escape sequences and their meanings are as
>   follows; the braces denote optional portions.
>         %%        A literal %.
>         %[p][l]R  The elapsed time in seconds.
>         %[p][l]U  The number of CPU seconds spent in user mode.
>         %[p][l]S  The number of CPU seconds spent in system mode.
>         %P        The CPU percentage, computed as (%U + %S) / %R.
>
> The optional p is a digit specifying the precision, the number of
>   fractional digits after a  decimal  point. A value of 0 causes  no
>   decimal point or fraction to be output.